# cannot use public key but can use password to connect WSL

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh

I had just set up my WSL for several days and the `sshd` on WSL was just working fine until today.(Both pub key and password were fine)

Now, I cannot connect to the WSL through public key now but password is ok.

I use frp to setup a port so I connect through that port to my WSL.

I tried to restart sshd: `sudo service ssh --full-restart` and frpc/frps, and the problem remains.

`authorized_keys` file is not modified, and owned by the correct user in its `~/.ssh` directory, and `sshd_config` seems like no problem as I checked with another ubuntu server (but not wsl).

I tried `ssh -vvv` and paste the following output

```
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\64687/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug2: key: .ssh/id_rsa (00000xxxxxxxx), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxx .ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: It may be helpful to stop the service, and in a separate terminal/tab/console run `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d` to get the debug from the *server* side.